# nopasswd in sudoers not working

Tags: sudo

I've got the following within my sudoers (a few comments removed for length):

```
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

root    ALL=(ALL:ALL)   ALL

%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL)   ALL

# Cmnd alias specification
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_EXPORTS_ADD = /usr/bin/chown 0\:0 *
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_EXPORTS_MOVE = /bin/mv * /etc/exports
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_NFSD_START = /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server start
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_NFSD_APPLY = /usr/sbin/exportfs -ar
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_EXPORTS_REMOVE = /bin/sed -r -e * d -ibak /tmp/exports

# Allow members of group sudo to control vagrant without having to type password at every vagrant up
%sudo   ALL=(root)  NOPASSWD: VAGRANT_EXPORTS_ADD, VAGRANT_EXPORTS_MOVE, VAGRANT_NFSD_START, VAGRANT_NFSD_APPLY, VAGRANT_EXPORTS_REMOVE

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Expected behaviour: When I type

```
cd ~
touch test
sudo chown 0:0 test
```

the file changes the owner without asking me for the password. What really happens is that I get prompted for the password every single time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to chown is `/bin/chown` not `/usr/bin/chown`. Change that and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I already guessed I would be something trivial ... I was really looking for the mistake for hours and then it's something as simple as this. So, very much thanks to you!

Answer (score -1):

You need an entry for the specific username you want to enable sudo access for. For example, if you want to give username "john" sudo access, you should have an entry in `/etc/sudoers`

```
john ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment: Hey, the other answer was my real problem. But I would although like to clarify that I think your answer is wrong, as what I did was to grant permissions so %sudo which is the sudoers syntax for the user group named sudo which I'm a member of. But thanks for your answer anyways!